# Multiple actions were found that match the request (GET)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api

I am defining 2 GET methods in my controller, one named "Favorites", and another simply named "Get". In my routes, I specifically map different URL routes to these 2 different methods.

However, when I hit /Api/MockUsers/Get?userId=2, I get the following error:

> Multiple actions were found that match the request

However, when I hit /api/MockUsers/1/favorites, it returns the data just fine.

I am confused because it seems I specifically routed /Api/MockUsers/Get?userId=2 to the ACTION "Get", not "Favorites", so why is MvC4 confused?

This is what my Routes look like:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
       name: "Users",
       routeTemplate: "api/MockUsers/{id}/favorites",
       defaults: new { controller = "MockUsers", action = "Favorites", id = 1 }
);

routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "Api_Get",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { action = "Get", id = RouteParameter.Optional },
        constraints: new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint("GET") }
);
```

In my controller, I have 2 methods:

```
[AcceptVerbs("GET")]
public UserFavorite Favorites(long id)
{
   Favorite f = new Favorite(1, "Favorite 1", "Favorite Type 1");
   UserFavorite userFavorite = new UserFavorite(1, f);

   return userFavorite;
}

public User Get(long userId)
{
   User u = _mockusersService.GetUser(userId);
   return u;
}
```

Comment: http://nuget.org/packages/routedebugger might help

Comment: You are going to confuse web api by naming an action `Get`, using a `GET` HTTP verb to call it and not attributing up the action.  By convention, Web API will think that your `Get` action should be invoked by the HTTP verb.  So, with the url: /Api/MockUsers?userId=2

Comment: ASP.NET Web api cannot mix 'traditional' and verb-based routing in the same ApiController. 
That's documented on codeplex (http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/184) and simplest solution is to 
get rid of your get action. Or you can follow this post (http://blog.appliedis.com/2013/03/25/web-api-mixing-traditional-verb-based-routing/) and ***(i)*** hardcode a default value instead of specifying that action is optional, 
***(ii)*** decorate your "verb-based controllers with the hardcoded default action name

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the default Webapi route, but changing the way you query.
Default route in WebApiConfig.cs:

```
configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute("API Default", "api/{controller}/{id}",
   new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
```

Assuming the webapi controller is named MockUsers, example calls would behave as follows:

GET **/Api/MockUsers?userId=2444** -->will resolve to a GET method that has userId as a parameter (your Get method endpoint).

GET **/Api/MockUsers?id=23444** -->will resolve to a GET method that has Id as a parameter (your favorites method endpoint).